# Turn cited docs into appendices

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have a set of TeX documents `{d}`. These documents need to refer to one another. To achieve this, I have a `references.bib` with one entry for each document in `{d}`. Inside each element of `{d}`, there are various `\cite` lines referring to the elements in `references.bib`.

Now I write a PhD thesis and I want to include the items in `{d}` as appendices. If I `\cite` them, they show up in the text as e.g. "[4]", which is not how one normally refers to appendices. I want references to the appendices to show up as e.g. "Appendix A". How an we achieve this?

If I `\label` the elements in `{d}` and then `\ref` them in the main text, I get what we want. However, this fails where the appendices refer to each other, because they would have to use `\cite` when compiled alone and `\ref` when part of the PhD thesis.

Is there a solution? The best thing I've thought of is making a separate `appendices.bib` for the PhD thesis. The question then becomes, how do I make the `\cite` commands show only the referent's title and also prevent the referred item from showing up in the bibliography?

### Minimal Working Example

The following files are just a set of stand-alone documents (the set `{d}` described above). In bananaMilkshake.tex, there is a normal citation using `\cite`.

**./banana-docs/bananaMilkshake.tex**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\subimport*{./}{bananaMilkshake-content}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

**./banana-docs/bananaMilkshake-content.tex**

```
First, peel a banana \cite{Sank:peelBanana}.
Then put it in the blender.
```

**./banana-docs/peelBanana.tex**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\subimport*{./}{peelBanana-content}

\end{document}
```

**./banana-docs/peelBanana-content.tex**

```
Separate the top part and then pull the peel off in three sections.
```

**./banana-docs/references.bib**

```
@misc{Sank:bananaMilkshake,
  author = {Sank, Daniel},
  title={How to Make a Banana Milkshake}
}

@misc{Sank:peelBanana,
  author = {Sank, Daniel},
  title={How to Peel a Banana}
}
```

Now we have a PhD thesis which wants to use the documents defined above as appendices:

**./thesis.tex**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

For details on how to make a banana milkshake, see appendix \ref{appendix:bananaMilkshake}.

\subimport*{./}{appendix}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{banana-docs/references}

\end{document}
```

**./appendix.tex**

```
\begin{appendices}

\chapter{How to Make a Banana Milkshake} \label{appendix:bananaMilkshake}
\subimport*{./banana-docs/}{bananaMilkshake-content}

\chapter{How to Peel a Banana} \label{appendix:peelBanana}
\subimport*{./banana-docs/}{peelBanana-content}

\end{appendices}
```

If you build thesis.tex, you find a line

```
For details on how to make a banana milkshake, see appendix A.
```

which is nice. However, in appendix A, you see

`First, peel a banana [1]. Then put it in the blender.`

and in the bibliography you see

```
[1] Daniel Sank. How to peel a banana.
```

which is not so nice. You want to be able to `\ref` Appendix B from within Appendix A, but you can't because a `\ref` in `bananaMilkshake.tex` has nothing to point to.

One thing that almost works is to make a separate .bib file for the thesis and `\ref` to the appendices inside it. This at least puts "Appendix A" in the bibliography, but that's not quite what we want.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.
That said, creating a new `\if` which is set to `true` in the thesis only and defining a new command which `\cite`s or `\ref`s depending on that `\if` might work?

Comment: @greyshade: Added MWE. I don't understand how to use the switch you suggest though, because then I'd have to use my new command in every document I might ever want to include in an appendix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this.
The basic idea is to use a home-made macro name in place of `\cite` and define that macro differently based on whether we're compiling as a stand-alone document or as part of a thesis.
A complete example is shown below.
Do not be intimidated by the large number of files; what's actually going on is really simple so just follow each step.

**/cite_as_appendix.tex**

```
\newcommand{\mycitetype}{Appendix}
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{
  \ref{#1}
}
```

**/cite_as_external.tex**

```
\newcommand{\mycitetype}{Ref.}
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{
  \cite{#1}
}
```

**/packages.tex**

```
\usepackage{import}
```

**/references-local.bib**

```
@misc{qubits,
author = {Sank, Daniel},
title = {Qubits}
}

@misc{iq_mixer,
author = {Sank, Daniel},
title = {IQ mixer}
}
```

**/iq-mixer/as-article.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{../packages.tex}
\input{../cite_as_external.tex}
\author{Daniel Sank}
\title{IQ Mixer}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\subimport*{./}{content}
\bibliographystyle{plain} \bibliography{../references-local}    
\end{document}
```

**/iq-mixer/as-appendix.tex**

```
\chapter{IQ Mixer} \label{iq_mixer}
\input{content.tex}
```

**/iq-mixer/content.tex**

```
This is a discussion of IQ mixers.
It will be useful when reading \mycitetype \mycite{qubits}.
```

**/qubits/as-article.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{../packages.tex}
\input{../cite_as_external.tex}
\author{Daniel Sank}
\title{Qubits}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\subimport*{./}{content}
\bibliographystyle{plain} \bibliography{../references-local}    
\end{document}
```

**/qubits/as-appendix.tex**

```
\chapter{Qubits} \label{qubits}
\input{content.tex}
```

**/qubits/content.tex**

```
This is a discussion of qubits.
You should read \mycitetype \mycite{iq_mixer} first.
```

**/thesis/main.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}

\input{../packages.tex}
\input{../cite_as_appendix.tex}
\author{Daniel Sank} \title{Book}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
This is a book about quantum computing.

\chapter{Science!}
To understand superconducting qubits, you should read \mycitetype \mycite{qubits} and \mycitetype \mycite{iq_mixer}.

\begin{appendix}
\subimport*{../iq-mixer/}{as-appendix}
\subimport*{../qubits/}{as-appendix}
\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```